# SQL Server change primary key to different [new] column and update foreign key references

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `model` with a `varchar` primary key of `alias`.

I have another table `device` and a table `error` that each have a foreign key that references `model`'s primary key of `alias`.

What I need to do is add a new column to `model` that will serve as the new primary key (`int indentity(1,1)`), therefore making `alias` just a plain old column. This means I will also need to properly update the foreign key references in `device` and `error` to reflect the new primary key column in `model`.

The problem is how to do this messy business cleanly and in the right order. I can modify the script we use to create the db from scratch with no problem, but the messy part is how to update an existing database.

I have limited knowledge of complex actions like this and rather than continue to spend the next day or two figuring out how to do this the right way and possibly borking my db a few times, I'd rather do it right the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'll need to perform several steps:

```
-- Assuming you have PK and FK names:
CREATE TABLE #one ( alias VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, meta VARCHAR(MAX) )
CREATE TABLE #device ( alias VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, device_info VARCHAR(MAX) )

ALTER TABLE #one ADD CONSTRAINT pk_one PRIMARY KEY ( alias )
ALTER TABLE #device ADD CONSTRAINT fk_device_one FOREIGN KEY ( alias ) REFERENCES #one( alias )

-- Data setup:
INSERT INTO #one ( alias, meta ) VALUES ( 'one', '' )
INSERT INTO #one ( alias, meta ) VALUES ( 'two', '' )
INSERT INTO #one ( alias, meta ) VALUES ( 'three', '' )
INSERT INTO #one ( alias, meta ) VALUES ( 'four', '' )

INSERT INTO #device ( alias, device_info ) VALUES ( 'one', '' )
INSERT INTO #device ( alias, device_info ) VALUES ( 'two', '' )
INSERT INTO #device ( alias, device_info ) VALUES ( 'three', '' )
INSERT INTO #device ( alias, device_info ) VALUES ( 'four', '' )

-- STEP 1: Add new fields
ALTER TABLE #one ADD one_id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
ALTER TABLE #device ADD one_id INT

-- STEP 2: Update dependent table data
UPDATE #device SET #device.one_id = #one.one_id FROM #device, #one WHERE #device.alias = #one.alias

-- STEP 3: Update Constraints on primary table
ALTER TABLE #one DROP CONSTRAINT pk_one
ALTER TABLE #one ADD CONSTRAINT pk_one PRIMARY KEY ( one_id )

-- STEP 4: Update FK Constraints
ALTER TABLE #device DROP CONSTRAINT fk_device_one
ALTER TABLE #device ADD CONSTRAINT fk_device_one FOREIGN KEY ( one_id ) REFERENCES #one( one_id )
```

I think it's possible to query system tables to harvest your constraint IDs and rewrite the above code as a stored procedure so that you only need to call the SPU to update dependent/client table data and build constraints. Let me know if you'd like more of an example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the identity column to Model.
2. Add new FK columns to Device and Error.
3. Update Device and Error, setting the new FK columns to the value of Model's new PK, where the old FK = the old PK (Alias).
4. Drop the old FK columns from Device and Error